# vue-router : why watch on $route trigger when previous queries rewrite with same values

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, watch

i have a `button` in my project when i click on it two `queries` added to `URL`

```js
onClickBtn(){
   this.$router.push({queries: {name:'kevin' , age:21} })
}
```

and I have a `watch` on `$route`

```js
watch:{
   $route:function(){
       // call API
   }
}
```

and when i click on that `button` severall time

`watch` calls my `API` every time although **nothing** has **changed**

and this make a **problem** form me

because **nothing** has **changed** in `route` But `API` is **called** and the **same data** is

received .

what should I do to **avoid** calling API in `watch` , when `queries` don't changed ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the answer that [Cristian provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825801/8816585), you could also even double-check if your stuff has changed before even pushing a new object to your router.

Like this

```js
checkIfUpdateNeeded && this.$router.push({queries: {name: 'kevin', age:21 } })
```

That way, you will have less moving parts and you won't have a trigger in the watcher for "nothing", especially if you're pushing a bigger object and want to make a deep-diff between 2 objects.

Answer (score 3):

The object you are pushing on the router is always different, that's why the $route watch is launched.
You can compare the data you receive in the watch, so that when they are different then you invoke the API:

```js
watch:{
   '$route' (newRoute, lastRoute){
       // Check if query is different
       // call API
   }
}
```